# Formatted output in ruby using p function

Tags: ruby

How can we obtain formatted output using **`p`** function. of ruby.
I need to print a float with exactly two decimal places.
I want to do it using minimum characters so i want to use **`p`** function instead of `puts` and `printf`.

i have tried this 
`printf"%.2f",a.abs/2`
Any idea on how to reduce characters ?

Comment: Perhaps good to know for you: You are playing [Code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) and there is also http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

`inspect` is the method you need to override for `p`

```
class Float
  def inspect
    sprintf "%.2f", self
  end
end
```

Result

```
p 12.0
#=> 12.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're ok about a string being returned, you can use use [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf)

```
sprintf "%.2f", 1.234
=> "1.23"
```

Note that `printf` is really just sugar for `IO.write(sprint())` so the above should be considered equiavelent.

Comment: I want to reduce number of characters , sprintf is having more

Comment: I don't understand your point.  What do you want to reduce exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `String#%`

> str % arg → new_str
>
> Format—Uses str as a format specification, and returns the result of applying it to arg. If the format specification contains more than one substitution, then arg must be an Array or Hash containing the values to be substituted. See Kernel::sprintf for details of the format string.

In your example:

```
a = 5.3
p"%.2f"%a
```

If you use a formula you need additional braces:

```
p"%.2f"%(a.abs/2)
```